# No mostrar registros dónde la suma de una columna sea 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hola estoy realizando un procedure para mostrar la relación de ventas por marca, tengo lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @fechaInicial DATETIME = '01/01/2019'
DECLARE @fechaFinal DATETIME = '31/01/2019'
DECLARE @id_municipio DECIMAL(18,0) = NULL
DECLARE @id_marca DECIMAL(18,0) = NULL
BEGIN

    SET @fechainicial = @fechainicial+' 00:00:00'
    SET @fechafinal = @fechafinal+' 23:59:59' 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #ConjuntosDatos(
        valor DECIMAL(18,0),
        id_marca DECIMAL(18,0),
        id_municipio DECIMAL(18,0)  
    )

    insert into #ConjuntosDatos
            SELECT DISTINCT F.valor,a.id_marca, F.id_municipio 
            FROM factura F
            INNER JOIN detalle_factura df ON df.id_factura = F.id_factura
            INNER JOIN articulo a ON a.articuloid = df.articuloid
            WHERE F.fecha >= @fechaInicial and F.fecha <= @fechaFinal
            AND ((@id_municipio IS NULL) OR (f.id_municipio = @id_municipio))
            AND ((@id_marca IS NULL) OR (a.id_marca = @id_marca))           
END
        BEGIN

        SELECT m.nombre as marca,
            (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1048) as Arauca,
            (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1049) as Arauquita,
            (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1051) as Fortul,
            (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1052) as PtoRondon,
            (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1053) as Saravena,
            (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1054) as Tame,
            (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1125) as PtoJordan,
            (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca) Total
         FROM marca m
         DROP TABLE #ConjuntosDatos 
END
```

de mi query anterior obtengo los siguientes registros
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que pretendo realizar es que las filas cuyos campo total sea igual a cero no se muestren. Que puedo hacer para lograr esto

Ejemplo: El item: 6, 7, 17, 18, 19, 20 no se mostrarian ya que el total es `cero`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente tienes dos formas:

#### 1. Usando una subconsulta

```
SELECT  *
        FROM (SELECT    m.nombre as marca,
                        (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1048) as Arauca,
                        (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1049) as Arauquita,
                        (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1051) as Fortul,
                        (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1052) as PtoRondon,
                        (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1053) as Saravena,
                        (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1054) as Tame,
                        (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca and id_municipio =1125) as PtoJordan,
                        (select isnull(SUM(valor),0) from #ConjuntosDatos where id_marca = m.id_marca) Total
                    FROM marca m
            ) T
            WHERE T.Total <> 0
```

Tu consulta final la puedes escribir dentro de otro `FROM` por lo que puedes acceder a las columnas calculadas como `Total` de forma transparente.

#### 2. Usando un `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  m.nombre as marca,
        SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN id_municipio = 1048 THEN d.valor ELSE 0 END, 0))   AS  Arauca,
        SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN id_municipio = 1049 THEN d.valor ELSE 0 END, 0))   AS  Arauquita,
        SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN id_municipio = 1051 THEN d.valor ELSE 0 END, 0))   AS  Fortul,
        SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN id_municipio = 1052 THEN d.valor ELSE 0 END, 0))   AS  PtoRondon,
        SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN id_municipio = 1053 THEN d.valor ELSE 0 END, 0))   AS  Saravena,
        SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN id_municipio = 1054 THEN d.valor ELSE 0 END, 0))   AS  Tame,
        SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN id_municipio = 1125 THEN d.valor ELSE 0 END, 0))   AS  PtoJordan,
        SUM(ISNULL(d.valor,0))                                                  AS  Total

        FROM marca m
        LEFT JOIN #ConjuntosDatos d
            on d.id_marca = m.id_marca
        GROUP BY m.nombre
        HAVING SUM(ISNULL(d.valor,0)) <> 0
```

Esta solución es mucho más óptima, por que dejamos de usar subconsultas a nivel de columnas, algo que no suele ser del todo óptimo. La diferencia con tu consulta es que usamos una suma condicional de acuerdo al `municipio` y el filtro final hay que implementarlo mediante el `HAVING` ya que el total es un `SUM` del `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado algo así como:

```
where total<>0
```